# QT: Влияет ли обновление прокси модели на основную модель?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть основная ListModel с пользователями. Для нее создается прокси модель, в которой к каждому пользователю добавляется его группа в определенной команде (если пользователя нет в команде, то он отфильтровывается). Делается это так, потому что в проекте есть много команд, и в каждой команде у пользователя отдельная группа, а прокси модель будет использоваться только внутри одной команды.

Вопрос такой: если я буду внутри прокси модели вызывать beginResetModel, dataChanged, то будет ли это влиять на основную модель? Не получится ли так, что из-за ресета одной прокси модели, все другие модели тоже перестроятся?

Comment: При чтении, по цепочке, это затронет только прокси и его исходную/основную модель. Остальные только если в исходную модель будут вноситься изменения (удаление, вставка, пересоздание)